# Javascript to render charts not working with .getJSON

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

Correction: /devicedata to /products - that was a typo..

I have built a node-express app which I am using to to plot a graph from the data retrieved from mongo database. I have tried two external libraries Chart.js and Canvas.js. Both work perfectly fine when the data is hard-coded in the javascript. The moment I use $.getJSON to retrieve the data from database it stops working. On the server side code is as below:

```
app.get('/products', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('products').find().toArray(function (err, items) {
       res.json(items);
    });
});
```

On the client side code is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("/products", function (result) {

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            title:{
                text: "Temperatures recorded this year"
                },
            data: [
                {
                    type: "column",
                    dataPoints: result,
                }
            ]
        });

        chart.render();
    });
});
</script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
</div>
```

Is there an alternative to .getJSON to retrieve data from database (mongo in this case) ? The chart is rendering as a blank canvas

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: How does the `/devicedata` route fit into this - Is the clientside code accessed at `http://<app>/devicedata`? What does the `/products` route look like?

Comment: I have pasted the route code on the top (server side code) . This simply fetches json data from the database.                                            [
  {
    "_id": "55266aa3960e7253a8b9a200",
    "deviceid": "b827ebe4be30",
    "cputemp": "47.62"
  },
  {
    "_id": "55266c87360b2e87b32371ad",
    "deviceid": "b827ebe4be30",
    "cputemp": "48.62"
  }
]

Comment: I cannot see any errors on the browser console

Comment: Like @olan said, unless you're doing something you're not showing us, the server side code should read `app.get('/products', function(req, res)`.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo.. corrected /devicedata to /products. Also, I have changed $(document).ready(function () to window.onload = function  and the charts are rendering now..